# drivers ATI Radeon HD 4550 no Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ati

What do you recommend! I don know hou to proceed. In system settings, adittional drivers says there is no proprietary drivers. I saw in some foruns that have occured crashes in same situations. The thing is that when I want to play heavier games, the screen goes black immediatly (doesn t  and will not come out of it.  I have to reset in the button ..i think it shoud be related with drivers.

Answer (score 0):

You can find AMD proprietary driver for HD4550 here :

http://support.amd.com/fr-fr/download/desktop/legacy?product=Legacy2&os=Linux%20x86_64

Unfortunately they are not compatible with kernel version > 3.4 
(12.04 LTS is now 3.8)
I tried myself last year  and was forced to renounce because there was something missing in the kernel and I couldn't compile the module (I don't remember what was missing, something about memory mapping if I remember).

Now I found that thread :

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/993427

looks at the patch in comment #14. 
So it seems that in between someone managed to patch the drivers.

I am trying to rewrite the patch for that new version version,  for the moment it is not too difficult I will let you know about my progress
(Don't thanks me I do it  for myself :) ).

*If someone has already managed to patch the legacy driver he is welcome here.*

Comment: Ok my friend, i will wait!! Another thing. I only can run Ubuntu in 2D mode - thatś because of the drivers too, or is it another thing!? My specs are these:O SO is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64 bit) graphics card is ATI Radeon HD 4550 memory: 2,9 GiB Processor: Intel® Pentium(R) D CPU 3.40GHz × 2 Gráficos: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV710 SO: 64-bit Disco: 489,0 GB

Comment: Another thing! Ares these specs, adequate to Ubuntu 12.04?